# Why does this code get a "ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)" error?

Tags: python, valueerror, unpack

I am doing this for my teacher and most of this code works great. Only at the very end ("   lastf.write(key, value)") I get the error "ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)"

```
    import json
# --1--
file = open("C:\\Users\\PycharmProjects\\p5.txt", 'w')

for i in range (4):
    a = input("enter a sentence")
    file.write(a+"\n")

file.close()

file2 = open("C:\\Users\\PycharmProjects\\p5.txt", 'r')
lines = file2.read().splitlines()
last_line = lines[-1]
print(last_line)

# --2--


def splitname():

    textf = open("C:\\Users\\PycharmProjects\\linuxEtcPassword.txt", 'r')

    ditailsd = {}
    for line in textf:
        newsplit = line.replace('\n', ' ').split(":")
        nv = {newsplit[0]: newsplit[2]}
        ditailsd.update(nv)
    dict1 = sorted(ditailsd.keys())
    conlst = {dict1[d]: dict1[d + 1] for d in range(0, len(dict1)-1, 2)}
    print(conlst)

    lastf = open("C:\\Users\\PycharmProjects\\linuxEtcPassword1.txt", 'w')
    for key, value in conlst:
        lastf.write(key, value)


file.close()

splitname()
```

Answer (score 0):

file.write('takes an argument /n will add a new line')
youre trying to write two items, are you trying to write something like,
key1, value1,
key2, value2 ?

Comment: yes, I am trying to write a dict to a text file

Comment: ok sure, you can use something like file.write(f"{key}:{value}\n")

Comment: Put your comments in the answer so I can mark it with a "check". ty

Answer (score 0):

you can use something like file.write(f"{key}:{value}\n")